# Comparing date in string format to utcNow in Get Items Filter Query

Tags: power-automate, power-platform

**Requirement:**

I'm trying to filter a Get Items action using a date in a string format (e.g. 23/11/2023). I want to only return items when that date (which we'll call FSAGDate) is in the future.

**Problem:**

Currently I'm having real trouble just converting the string to a date format. I know that all I need to say is:

```
FSAGDate gt utcNow()
```

But it's the conversion of FSAGDate that keeps throwing up errors. This is an example of my current flow:

[image]

**Current Attempts:**

I have tried to following bits of code to convert FSAGDate in the Filter Query:

```
parseDateTime('FSAGDate ','en-US','yyyy/MM/dd')

formatDateTime('FSAGDate , 'yyyy/MM/dd')

convertToUtc(concat(split(item()?['FSAGDate'],'/')[2],'-',split(item()?['FSAGDate'],'/')[1],'-',split(item()?['FSAGDate'],'/')[0]), 'Greenwich Standard Time')
```

I have tried that last one both with and without the convertToUtc function, but I always get something along the lines of the following message:

> "Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Get_items'
> inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language expression
> 'convertToUtc(concat(split('FSAGDate','/')[2],'-',split('FSAGDate','/')[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zNqr.png),'-',split('FSAGDate','/')[0]),
> 'Greenwich Standard Time')' cannot be evaluated because array index
> '2' is outside bounds (0, 0) of array. "

If I need to covert my date string prior to it going in the Get Items Filter Query, I really don't know how to do that...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The screenshot where it’s trying to filter on utcNow(), what error do you get for that?

Answer (score 0):

In your Filter Query try expression:

```
utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

And is FSAGDate column a Date/Time column in SharePoint or other?

Answer (score 0):

You said that the right formula is :

```
FSAGDate gt utcNow()
```

but you insert:

```
FSAGDate gt 'utcNow()'
```

(with quotes around utcNow)

No need to convert/cast/split anything if FSAGDate is already a date. Use the first formula for the filter.